# Every variety contains open affine normal subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to prove this?
I think that the starting point here is to use the fact that the set $\{x\in X \,|\, X\, \text{is normal at}\, x\}$ is open. What do I do next?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next thing you do is use the fact that every open subset of a variety contains an affine open. Indeed, let $X$ be a variety and $\emptyset\ne V\subseteq X$ open. By definition, you can cover $X=U_1\cup\cdots\cup U_n$ with open affine subsets, and therefore there is some $i$ with $U_i\cap V\ne\emptyset$. Furthermore, $U_i\cap V$ is an open subset of $V$, plus it is an open subset of the affine variety $U_i$. Therefore, there is some $f\in\mathcal O_{U_i}(U_i)$ such that $D(f)\subseteq V\cap U_i$. Now this $D(f)$ is affine, since $D(f)=\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal O_{U_i}(U_i)_f)$ and it is open in $V$ as desired.

Since being normal is a local property, every point of $D(f)$ is normal, hence $D(f)$ is a normal variety.

Comment: You also need that $V$ is nonempty here.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury: Good point, fixed.

Comment: Right, but what I meant is that he has to establish that the set of normal points is open *and nonempty*.

Comment: Jesko, thank you. Actually I know how to prove that the set of normal points is open and nonempty so it is not a big deal.